# How to create a floor in a sceneBox in three.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm relatively new to three.js and while experimenting, I was trying to expand on this tutorial: http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/materials_cars.html in an attempt to make it more realistic. Is there a way for me to place the car onto the 'floor' of the scenecube? 
When I had attempted to move the car position lower, the sceneCube had also expanded in the same amount so that the car remained in the center of the room.

Is there a way for me to basically create a room where the car is on the floor?

Comment: First off, you might want to use a more recent version of the demo: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html

Comment: This version still has the car model floating; what modification can I make so that the car actually gets moved to the floor?